# How do I run a remote command in a specific session on a remote computer?

Tags: powershell

thanks in advance!

I found this code to bring a running process (Notepad) to Foreground

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((get-process notepad).MainWindowTitle)
```

The above only works on my Local computer, I'd like to run it on a remote computer with currently logged on user...

I also have a script that enumerates the session on a remote computer, in this example I can
choose let say session 1 and it will logoff that user session.

```
$pc = Read-Host "Computer Name"
echo $pc
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock { quser } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$session = Read-Host "Session ID: (enter to quit)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If (!$session)
{
echo "No Sessions found"
Exit
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock { logoff $using:session } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Can I somehow do something similar, get the session ID and use it to run the top command to bring Notepad to front, or any other/easier way to accomplish it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: regardless of what credentials are specified for invoking the command over, PowerShell will run in a "*sub-session*"; not the users true session. What you're looking for is to run the command under the users context which can be accomplished using Task Scheduler.

Comment: thank you, could it be done using PSEXEC?

Comment: Perhaps using the System account, but as mentioned, you can do this using Task Scheduler from within PowerShell. Are you in a domain environment?

Comment: yes, I am in a domain env.

Comment: You can't do it in PowerShell, but it's not impossible to do it. Just very inconvenient. Use PS to set up a scheduled task as the target user session, with the option to only run when user is logged on. The first block of code should be what you run in the PowerShell exe when you set up the action. Register the task, then run it. Downside is if you're configuring a task to run as a specific user, you need to provide the user's credential to register the task. You can't cheat and use the SYSTEM user here because you ***must*** impersonate the user of the target session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as myself, and [Bender the Greatest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584676/bender-the-greatest) mention, you can take the *Scheduled Task* route to run it under the users context:

```
try {
    $command  = "(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((get-process notepad).MainWindowTitle)"
    $computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction "Stop") {
            $username = Get-CimInstance -ClassName "Win32_ComputerSystem" -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
                if (-not$Username) { 
                    Write-Output -InputObject "No user logged into: $Computer."
                    Break 
                }
                else {
                    Write-Verbose -Message "Current logged in user: $Username."
                    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
                        $time = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(2).ToString("HH:mm")
                        
                        #The name of your scheduled task.
                        $taskName = "MainWindow"

                        #Task description.
                        $description = "Bring notepad to front."
                        
                        #Task action - what it should do.
                        $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' `
                                                              -Argument "-Command $using:command"

                        #Task trigger
                        $taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $time -Once
                        
                        #Register the scheduled task.
                        Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName `
                                               -Description $description `
                                               -Action $taskAction `
                                               -User $using:username #| Out-Null

                        #Run the task
                        Start-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $taskName #| Out-Null

                        #optional timer
                        #Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

                        #Remove the newly created task since it's done running
                        Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Confirm:$false
                       
                    } -ComputerName $computer
                }
        }

}
catch {
    Write-Output -InputObject $_.Exception.Message
}
```

You may have to remove the pre-pended domain in the username for Task Scheduler to properly find the user in AD (*ran into this issue before - should work though*). As you can see it's a tedious process but, it can be done. The biggest hassle is trying to piece it all together as it can become a bit confusing.

If you have the time, I'd recommend turning it into a function that accepts a `-Command`, and `-FilePath` argument for future use as well as robustness.

---

*I haven't tested it out, but I wouldn't see why it wouldn't work. You may have to provide administrative credentials given your environment but, when using Kerberos you should be good; as long as your session is ran as Admin.*

Comment: thank you, will give it a try and see....

Comment: Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much!   Was able to accomplish it using your guidance... here's my code in case it can help others... sorry not sure how to paste it in 'code' format in the comment below...

Comment: $pc = Read-Host "Computer Name"
$folder = "\\" + $pc + "\c$\windows\temp"
echo $folder
    Copy-Item "\\workgroup\files\chat.ps1" -Destination "$folder"
    
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock {   

SCHTASKS /Create /tn "Show-Chat-Window"  /tr "Powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File c:\windows\temp\chat.ps1" /ru interactive /sc onlogon /f
}

Comment: I think it should be `TaskName` instead of `TaskPath` in the `Start-ScheduledTask` command